# getssl cannot reach challenge token url

Tags: apache-http-server, ssl-certificate

I am using getssl (https://github.com/srvrco/getssl) to renew my ssl certificate. I get this message when I try to renew my domain:

```
Check all certificates
Registering account
Verify each domain
Verifying mydomain.org.au
copying challenge token to /home/www/mydomain/.well-known/acme-challenge/k_K<blah>
getssl: for some reason could not reach http://mydomain.org.au/.well-known/acme-challenge/k_K<blah> - please check it manually
```

If I paste the URL into my browser, it gets converted to

> [http://mydomain.org.au.well-known/acme-challenge/k_K\](http://mydomain.org.au.well-known/acme-challenge/k_K%5C)

In other the words, the slash at the end of the domain name is removed.

Could this be a problem with handling of dots in URLs in my Apache config? I've tried this unsuccessfully:

```
<Directory /home/www/mydomain/.well-known>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Post the output from `curl -I -L http://mydomain.org.au/.well-known/acme-challenge/k_K<blah>`. If you include your domain, you can often get a fact-based answer quickly. If you hide that information, we have to guess. The `<Directory>` directive is not causing this problem. I will **guess** that you have a poorly formed redirection occurring. Post your `<VirtualHost>` and `.htaccess` details.

Answer (score 0):

I found the offending line in vhosts.conf - have removed it:

> Redirect permanent / https://mydomain.org.au